# Detecting CDROM media removal/insertion in Linux

Tags: linux, device, cd-rom

Is there a clean way to detect or receive events when a user inserts or removes a CD on a Linux platform?

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Udev monitors hardware and forwards events to dbus. You just need some dbus listener. A quick check using the dbus-monitor tool shows this in my system:

dbus-monitor --system

```
signal sender=:1.15 -> dest=(null destination) serial=144 path=/org/freedesktop/UDisks; interface=org.freedesktop.UDisks; member=DeviceChanged
   object path "/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sr0"
```

This is the DeviceChanged event from Udisks, and the device path is included.

So, in whatever programming language you want that supports dbus bindings you can listen for those (system bus) events.

Comment: udev forwards events to hotplug.  You apparently have hotplug attached to dbus, but this isn't true of all linux distributions.

Comment: @Ben No, the latest udev forwards to dbus, I have no hotplug on my system. This is true for the newest udev/opendesktop installations. That's what I have with my Gentoo installation. But it's true that other distros may not yet have this.

Comment: That's funny, I don't see a dependency from udev on dbus, or any USE flag.  Must be an indirect dependency.

Comment: @Ben @Keith: udisks is not part of udev.  Rather, udisks is a D-Bus service which manages disks, including handling information coming from udev.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally there has been [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) (Hardware Abstraction Layer) for this, but the web page says

> HAL is in maintenance mode - no new
>   features are added. All future
>   development focuses on udisks, UPower
>   and other parts of the stack. See
>   Software/DeviceKit for more
>   information.

and the DeviceKit page lists

> udisks, a D-Bus interface for dealing with storage devices

So [udisks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks) should probably be what you are asking for.

Comment: udisks, if it's available, is definitely the way to go.  It presents as a DBus interface (accessible from most any reasonable programming language), and has a command line tool (udisks) which can be parsed by pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I was able to find was Halevt. Halevt is apparently a higher level abstraction than using HAL directly. It uses an XML based configuration file that may or may not be to your liking. The configuration file properties documentation is somewhat lacking. A list of all the supported properties are listed here:

http://www.marcuscom.com/hal-spec/hal-spec.html

Also, the link to Halevt: http://www.nongnu.org/halevt/